# Silicon Wafer orientation

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm confused about how `<110>` direction is determined for `[100]`, `[110]` or `[111]` wafers. I found a book chapter which just confused me even more. From the image below, I understand how `<110>` is determined on the `[110]` wafer but not the other two. I'm also having a hard time understanding what different planes would look like on the `[111]` and `[110]` wafer. I would appreciate a resource for Silicon wafers specifically (not necessarily crystallography)

[image]

Comment: Try here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystal-structure  https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=silicon+crystal+111

Answer (score 0):

Draw a vector in your coordinate system from your origin to the coordinate.  First digit is x, second y, third z.

This vector is the normal to the orientation plane.  That's as far as miller notation goes.

From there the 110 should be relative to the primary flat, wherever that ends up.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the last sentence "From there the 110 should be relative to the primary flat, wherever that ends up."

Comment: So what I understand is that once the wafer is sliced from the ingot, the work of planes is done and we don't use it for mask pattern alignment. Am I correct? Of course I understand that the material properties are different for (100) vs. (111) wafers but once we've selected the wafer type we're done with the surface planes and the alignment of mask pattern is relative to the primary flat.

Comment: Yup.  That's as much as I understood.  Not an expert and I haven't yet had reason to learn more.